# Jupyter notebook gui missing Java kernel

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm using below docker to use `IJava` kernel to my jupyter notebook.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG NB_USER="some-user"
ARG NB_UID="1000"
ARG NB_GID="100"

RUN apt-get update || true && \
    apt-get install -y sudo && \
    useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u $NB_UID $NB_USER && \
    chmod g+w /etc/passwd && \
    echo "${NB_USER}    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:    ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    # Prevent apt-get cache from being persisted to this layer.
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
    python3-pip git curl unzip

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python & \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install packaging jupyter ipykernel awscli jaydebeapi
    RUN python -m ipykernel  install --sys-prefix


# Install Java kernel

RUN mkdir ijava-kernel/ && cd ijava-kernel && curl -LO  https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.3.0/ijava-1.3.0.zip && \
    unzip ijava-1.3.0.zip && \
    python install.py --sys-prefix && \
    rm -rf ijava-kernel/ 

RUN jupyter kernelspec list

ENV SHELL=/bin/bash
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/

WORKDIR /home/$NB_USER
USER $NB_UID
```

As soon as I run the docker image, inside the container:

```
some-user@023f579253ec:~$ jupyter kernelspec list                                                                                                                            ─╯
Available kernels:
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  java       /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/java
some-user@023f579253ec:~$
```

As well as, the console with kernel java is also installed and working as per README.md

```
 jupyter console --kernel java

In [2]: String helloWorld = "Hello world!"

In [3]: helloWorld
Out[3]: Hello world!
```

But as soon as I run open the `jupyter notebook` inside the container, I only see Python3 kernel not the Java. see attached image.[image: No Java Kernel Listing]

can anyone help me out to add the Java Kernel to Notebook GUI?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/issues/69)'s GitHub. The discussion thread mentions a few Docker Images that address your issue: [1](https://github.com/jbindinga/java-notebook), [2](https://hub.docker.com/r/jbindinga/java-notebook), [3](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/jupyter/Dockerfile).